# NSOutlineView: How to have different custom color for item with and without child?

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview

I've a custom subclass of NSOutlineView that use a TextFieldCell as cell. Some items that has child (that represents a group of child).

I want to have a custom color for the items with child and another custom color for the items without child. I tried to change it in IB but the color changes only for the child items and in code I can also set a custom color but only for the child items. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I think you can achieve it by overriding the - (void)drawRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex clipRect:(NSRect)clipRect   in NSOutlineView  subclass.

Comment: Yes, after a deep research I think that this is the only solution. The problem is that I need to implement manually all the drawing of cell. Anyone know a good starting point for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough research seems that the only way to do that is to override the `drawRow:` method on the `NSOutlineView` subclass

Answer (score 0):

you can also implement NSOutlineViewDelegate method
- (void) outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell
      forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn*)aTableColumn item:(id)item;

in it you could have a part that goes something along the lines of:

```
if ([self outlineView:self isGroupItem: item]){
NSColor *color;
if ([item.children count] == 0) {
color = [NSColor redColor];
}
else {
color = [NSColor blueColor];
}
[aCell setDrawsBackground:YES];
[aCell setBackgroundColor: color];
}
```

Sorry about formatting, i'm still rather new at this.
This should work, since I've used this code for something similar.
I hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: change item.isGroup to [self outlineView:self isGroupItem: item].
i couldn't remember the exact method, so i put item.isGroup just to indicate that part of code should be executed only for group rows. i'll edit my answer to avoid any confusion from now on.